# left join not working in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'student' table and 'attendance' table 
If a student is absent I just enter student ID and date in attendance table.
Now I want to retrieve all students and their attendance on a particular date
However when I am trying left Join, it gives me data of a particular student absent on that particular date

Table 'student' structure and sample data:

```
id|name (varchar field)
1 |xxx
6 |yyy
```

Table 'attendance' structure and sample data:

```
id|date (date field)|student_id (integer field)
1 |2015-10-15       | 1
1 |2015-10-16       | 6
```

My query

```
SELECT *
FROM student.id, student.name, attendance.date
  LEFT JOIN attendance
    ON student.id = attendance.student_id
WHERE attendance.date = '2015-10-15'
```

The output is

```
1   xxx 2015-10-15
```

However required output is

```
1   xxx 2015-10-15
6   yyy NULL (or a blank)
```

Comment: Please help us help you by providing an http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Whenever you use Where clause in query it will return only data which satisfies where condition, So you need to use that condition in `ON` instead of `WHERE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the output you desire you need to move your condition `attendance.date = '2015-10-15'` from `WHERE` clause, to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT student.id, student.name, attendance.date
FROM student
  LEFT JOIN attendance
    ON student.id = attendance.student_id AND attendance.date = '2015-10-15'
```

In this case date will be used during the join. If you use it in `WHERE` clause, the filtering is done after data is joined, so the second line from your desired output is filtered out

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9aae/1) demonstrating the solution

Comment: Perfect. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the primary table. You need to move the `FROM` to the end of the `SELECT` portion, then actually name a table

```
SELECT *, student.id, student.name, attendance.date
FROM student
  LEFT JOIN attendance
    ON student.id = attendance.student_id
WHERE attendance.date = '2015-10-15'
```

Comment: Also, you should reconsider the SELECT statement. You are selecting `*`, which may throw an ambiguous problem error, but also selecting specific items from each table.